# SSRS get sum on an expression field

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

Suppose I have the following data:

> ```
> TimeTable
> Person  Week   Date        EnterTime ExitTime PeriodDiff
> ----------------------------------------------------
> John    1      01.01.2018  09:15     10:35    1:20
> John    1      01.01.2018  10:55     12:23    1:28
> John    1      01.01.2018  13:00     17:35    4:35
> John    1      02.01.2018  09:00     16:35    7:35
> John    2      08.01.2018  09:05     11:40    2:35
> John    2      08.01.2018  16:15     19:35    3:20
> John    2      09.01.2018  10:50     21:57    11:07
> ```

I am trying to make a report about the weekly and daily time people were in the company.
So I am trying to create the following report:

> ```
>                  +[WeekGroup]                                                  +
>                  ---------------------------------------------------------------
>                                 +[DateGroup]                                   +
>                  WeeklyTotal    ------------------------------------------------
> Person                          FirstEntry     LastExit      TimeInside   Period
> [PersonGroup]    <<Exp3>>       Min[EnterTime] Max[ExitTime] <<Exp1>>     <<Exp2>>
> ```

Exp1 = Max(ExitTime) - Min(EnterTime) 
 
Exp2 = Sum(PeriodDiff)
Exp3 should be Sum(Max(ExitTime) - Min(EnterTime)) for each day

Everything works except for Exp3.
Problem is Exp3 is outside of the DateGroup so the min/max values refer to each of those in the respected week. Also I cannot use the sum of period because of the gaps in time.
How can I get the sum of each weeks calculated time differance? Meaning sum(Exp1) ?

Comment: Seems you do not need all the detail data in your dataset to create the report. You could make aggregations on the query  like SELECT Person, Week, Date, Min(EnterTime), Max(ExitTime), SUM(PeriodDiff)...GROUP BY Person, Week, Date

Comment: @niktrs I could not understand what you mean by that. Problem is for each day min and max times are aggregated and I need a sum of their differance for each week. Since the actual data contains more than 1 week and 1 person it becomes a big problem to calculate inside the report with a single dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following expression to get the `Max()` or `Min()` inside the group or outside the group, if you add the scope to the aggregate function:

```
'Returns the max of the whole DataSet
=Min(Fields!ExitTime.Value), "YourDataSetName") 

 'Returns the max of the group with the name 'YourGroupName'
=Min(Fields!ExitTime.Value), "YourGroupName")
```

What you also can do, is to reverence to your first expression `Expr1()` with the following expression (lets assume the first expression is in `Textbox1`):

```
=Sum(ReportItems!Textbox1.Value)
```

Comment: Example is simplified, week data needs to be calculated per week per person. Max of DataSet would return only 1 person.